# Xcode 8 - Could not build module 'CoreFoundation' in ios10

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode8, xmppframework

using `Xcode 8`.
`iOS 10`

Objective-C

> Pod file consist :- pod 'XMPPFramework'

i want to integrate `XMPPFramework` in my project.
installed pods.
after installing pods when i open `xWorkspace`. these errors comes.

podfile :-

## Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, ‘8.0’

target 'Roj' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

# Pods for Roj

pod 'XMPPFramework'

target 'RojTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

target 'RojUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

these are the errors which comes in my project [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWIY2.png)

Comment: Please paste your Podfile into the question so we can see what is going on

Comment: now the question contains podfile.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution in Build settings ;

[image]

Comment: this is not working.
this field already contains "yes" in my xcode(project).

Comment: try this :  turning on: Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules

Comment: have done what you said above, but still the error exist .

have you see the image which consist errors ?

Comment: @Pramod : Any luck.. I am also struggling with same issue

Comment: @AlxVallejoup upvote to answer so we cen helps to other .

Comment: it is correct but some time it will works according to your dependencies .

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by implementing following changes.

1) Change the following flags in you Project's Build Settings.

[image: Flags shown in image]

2) Rename your module.modulemap files. Name them anything except module and then change the path of this renamed file in your Xcode.

Clean it, Build it, it will resolve the issue.

P.S - Other compilation issues will get resolved automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

- Go to Build Settings
- Search for Compile Source As
- Set it to Objective-C++

See this issue: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/issues/361#issuecomment-379013147